# Does gsettings have a GUI frontend?

Tags: gnome, dconf, gsettings

There is `dconf-editor` for `dconf`, but `dconf` is a low-level configuration system and direct use of it is discouraged. Users are recommended to use `gsettings` instead, but I cannot find a GUI tool for it.

By the way, the keys in `dconf` and `gsettings` don't always match. So it's not possible to use `dconf-editor` on `gsettings` IDs.

Comment: No. There's one gui tool and that's `dconf-editor`.

Comment: However, `dconf-editor` is [mentioned](https://developer.gnome.org/GSettings/#dconf-editor) among tools on GSettings page for developers.

Answer (score 0):

All I've been able to find (as of Debian **Stretch**) is **dconf-editor**.

Also, I've not seen anywhere that the use of **dconf-editor** is discouraged (I *have* seen, however, that the direct use of **gconf-editor** is discouraged, if that helps...).

Comment: Yes, but please note this https://askubuntu.com/questions/416556/shouldnt-dconf-editor-and-gsettings-access-the-same-database

Comment: And this https://askubuntu.com/questions/1216693/why-does-dconf-editor-think-that-my-schema-does-not-exist